# Incomplete upload of data using s3.putObject with node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a set of rows returned from a query. In this case 10,000 rows. I have verified and the rows and the count as valid.

I am trying to `JSON.stringify` those rows then directly upload them to S3 using **aws-lambda** with **node.js** using the following code:

```
var s3Params = {Bucket: 'mybucket', Key:'log.json', Body: JSON.stringify(rows), ContentType: "application/json"};
s3.putObject(s3Params, function(err,data) {console.log(JSON.stringify(err));});
```

But only 1000 of the 10000 rows are uploaded.

I'm new to node/javascript so not sure if I might be missing something. I have not seen any functional limit on `JSON.stringify` or `s3.putObject`.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: At first glance, you're describing a condition that is essentially impossible for specific reasons: a JSON object cannot be accidentally truncated and still be valid JSON... i.e. every `[` must be balanced by a `]`.  We can rule out `s3.putObject` because it has no contextual payload awareness (nor does S3 itself), and a problem here would create invalid JSON. (The limit is 5GB but exceeding that would throw an error). Similarly, S3 refuses to store objects that are not uploaded intact.  And if `JSON.stringify()` imposes random/unknown limits then the Internet as a whole is doomed.

Comment: So, my initial suggestion is to waste a little memory for troubleshooting purposes: `console.log('rows: ' + rows.length.toString());` `const j = JSON.stringify(rows);` `const xj = JSON.parse(j);` `console.log('json rows: ' + xj.length.toString());` ...then in s3Params, use `Body: j, ...`.  Verify whether, within the code, the original array really has... and JSON parses to... the expected number of rows.

Comment: Speculation: you're building this array with some kind of paginated API and you're uploading either the first or last set of 1000 entries due to async timing issues or another bug in another part of your code.  You might also use `JSON.stringify(rows,null,2)` to make the resulting JSON (stored in S3) a little more eyeball-friendly so you can examine the generated JSON a bit more easily.  I'm curious to see what this issue turns out to be.

Comment: Thanks, please see my full code in this new entry I made: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51446454/node-js-aws-lambda-inconsistent-s3-putobject-upload-of-large-data-object